# Display IconFile in DNN menu

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am trying to modify the default skin of DNN 9.3.2 to display the IconFile which I have set under page settings for each page.

To display the icon anywhere on a page I used

```
  <img src="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.IconFile) %>" />
```

but it's not what I want. 
It should appear like this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved:

```
<img src="[=ICON]" />
```